# Jetpack Compose: Custom VectorAsset Icon object similar to built-in `Icons.Default`

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-android-extensions, android-vectordrawable

It looks like the only way to go about loading custom icons from Android Vector Resources in the `res` folder is to do it within a `@Composable` function using the `vectorResource(R.drawable.myVectorName)` method.

This is great and all, but I like the syntax of fetching `VectorAssets` for the `Icon(asset: VectorAsset)` class, which looks like `Icon(Icons.Default.Plus)`.

It looks like the `vectorResource()` method uses an *internal* method called `loadVectorResource()`, and the methods it uses to read the actual XML file composing the vector asset file are also internal.

How would I go about creating an object like `MyAppIcons.Default.SomeIcon` in Jetpack Compose?

**EDIT**

So, I have sort-of found a solution. However, it would be nice to make my own extension/overloading of the built-in `Icon()` function, but I'm not sure if there is a proper way to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't using my brain. The answer is pretty easy.

The gist is, `Icon()` *is* a composable function, meaning that of course *vectorResource()* can be used there.

So, the correct approach is no secret... it's to make your own `MyAppIcon()` component, call `vectorResource()` and then return a normal `Icon()`, like so:

**Correct Way**

```
@Composable
fun MyAppIcon(
    resourceId: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    tint: Color = AmbientContentColor.current
) {
    Icon(
        asset = vectorResource(id = resourceId),
        modifier = modifier,
        tint = tint
    )
}
```

You can then create an object elsewhere, like so:

```
object MyAppIcons {
    val SomeIcon = R.drawable.someIcon
    val AnotherIcon = R.drawable.anotherIcon
}
```

When you put the two together, you can use it like this:

```
MyAppIcon(MyAppIcons.SomeIcon)
```

I'm hoping that Google just adds this override soon, allowing us to pass in resource IDs.

Answer (score 22):

from [Resources in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/resources#vector-assets)

Use the `painterResource` API to load either vector drawables or rasterized asset formats like PNGs. You don't need to know the type of the drawable, simply use `painterResource` in `Image` composables or `paint` modifiers.

```
// Files in res/drawable folders. For example:
// - res/drawable-nodpi/ic_logo.xml
// - res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_logo.png

// In your Compose code
Icon(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_logo),
    contentDescription = null // decorative element
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I went down the other route and extracted the logic from Jetpack Compose source code that turns an XML SVG path string into an `ImageVector`. In the end I came up with this:

```
fun makeIconFromXMLPath(
    pathStr: String,
    viewportWidth: Float = 24f,
    viewportHeight: Float = 24f,
    defaultWidth: Dp = 24.dp,
    defaultHeight: Dp = 24.dp,
    fillColor: Color = Color.White,
): ImageVector {
    val fillBrush = SolidColor(fillColor)
    val strokeBrush = SolidColor(fillColor)

    return ImageVector.Builder(
        defaultWidth = defaultWidth,
        defaultHeight = defaultHeight,
        viewportWidth = viewportWidth,
        viewportHeight = viewportHeight,
    ).run {
        addPath(
            pathData = addPathNodes(pathStr),
            name = "",
            fill = fillBrush,
            stroke = strokeBrush,
        )
        build()
    }
}
```

All you have to do is call this function with `pathStr` set to the value of `android:pathData` from the drawable XML file. Here's an example:

```
val AppleIcon by lazy { makeAppleIcon() }

// by Austin Andrews, found on https://materialdesignicons.com/
private fun makeAppleIcon(): ImageVector {
    return makeIconFromXMLPath(
        pathStr = "M20,10C22,13 17,22 15,22C13,22 13,21 12,21C11,21 11,22 9,22C7,22 2,13 4,10C6,7 9,7 11,8V5C5.38,8.07 4.11,3.78 4.11,3.78C4.11,3.78 6.77,0.19 11,5V3H13V8C15,7 18,7 20,10Z"
    )
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun AppleIconPreview() {
    Surface { 
        Icon(AppleIcon, "Apple")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: One very insightful and useful answer, thank you very much 

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to load asset using `Icon(Icons.Default.Plus)`. You need to make an extesion property

```
val androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons.Filled.FiveG : VectorAsset
    get() {

    }
```

but I don't see the way to get `VectorAsset` outside of composable function.
Of course you can do something like this

```
val androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons.Filled.FiveG : VectorAsset
    get() {
        return Assets.FiveG
    }

object Assets {
    lateinit var FiveG: VectorAsset
}

@Composable
fun initializeAssets() {
    Assets.FiveG = vectorResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_5g_24)
}
```

but it's a bad idea to have a composable with side effect. So i'm waiting for someone to find a way to convert SVG to `VectorAsset` Kotlin class or get `VectorAsset` object outside of composable function.